# How to Search Stack Overflow for a Stack Overflow Exception?

Tags: discussion, search

I'm trying to research a stack overflow exception with log4net.  However, when I google "log4net stack overflow" it causes anything related to stackoverflow.com to be listed.  Even when I google "log4net stackoverflow" or "log4net stackoverflowexception" it still seems to return only StackOverflow.com posts that are not related to a stack overflow.

I like having answers from SO, but google doesn't seem to understand that I'm not asking about the "Stack Overflow" website; I am asking about a literal stack-overflow issue.

Any suggestions?

The best I can figure is to use the search feature built into the SO web site, and type this:

> log4net stackoverflow

or

> log4net stackoverflowexception

However, I've never found the SO built-in search to rival google; I'm not sure how thorough are the results it provides.  The above searches gave me nothing on the topic.  Is that because there is nothing on the topic, or because the SO search facility is not as robust as google?

I should point out that, yes, I am receiving a stack-overflow emanating from within log4net.  I doubt I am the first to experience this, which is why I'm looking for answers...

Comment: Just spell out it: "log4net system.stackoverflowexception"

Comment: @Hans: I assume spelling it out "log4net system.stackoverflowexception" only works if the SO poster literally used the text string "system.stackoverflowexception".  I'm unsure I can count on that.

Comment: Six thousands hits is not enough??

Comment: The built-in search works probably better in this case if tags are used, i.e. the search criteria spelled as `[log4net] stackoverflow`

Comment: This reminds me of searching the web for html tags, waaaay back when I was learning the basics.

Comment: My first instinct would have been to search within the `[stackoverflow]` or `[stackoverflowexception]` tags (but in this case there are no hits with log4net as a search term).

Comment: Error occurred: Stack Overflow of words "Stack Overflow" found in this question.

Comment: Wouldn't searching `stackoverflow` for a `stackoverflow` cause a `stackoverflow`? o_O

Answer (score 78):

Try a Google search for `log4net "stackoverflowexception" site:stackoverflow.com`. That'll only match "stackoverflowexception" on SO, not general SO.

Comment: Or `log4net "stackoverflowexception" -site:stackoverflow.com`, to find stuff elsewhere.  (6290 results)

Comment: @HotLicks *Why* would you ever go anywhere else?

Comment: Google has implemented `"emphasis quotes"` where `"this means"` I mean the actual thing in the quotes, not `"something else"`.

Comment: This page is the first [google](https://www.google.com/?q=log4net%20%22stackoverflowexception%22%20site%3Astackoverflow.com) result. :P

Comment: @canon That's very [recursive](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+recursion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=fflb&q=recursion&spell=1) :D

Answer (score 13):

There's a less well known search page on Stack Exchange that is powered by google.  https://stackexchange.com/search?q=

It's the search in the upper right that typically has the text 'search all sites'.  This will indeed search all Stack Exchange sites.

For example, putting in the search criteria mentioned brings up [this set of results](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=log4net+stackoverflowexception), which now has this question as part of it too.  But it *is* all stack exchange sites.  While this one is turing out page after page of results for Stack Overflow, it can be quite useful for search results when you are looking for something that could occur on multiple sites such as information about [hashing a password](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=hash+password) which might be on Security.SE, SO, or P.SE depending on the nature of the question.

Answer (score 9):

I find that this search on Bing works ok:  `+"Stack overflow exception" in +log4net`

Answer (score 2):

There are tags for questions related to the concept of a stack overflow: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow), [stackoverflowexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowexception), and [stackoverflowerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowerror).

Answer (score 1):

You asked for suggestions. You can use `[tagname]` to narrow things down. `[log4net] stack overflow exception` [yields one result](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[log4net]+stack+overflow+exception).

On the right side of a search result page (such as the one I linked) there is a link titled "Advanced Search Tips". It provides additional tips such as user:1234, user:me, is:question, closed:yes and more.